# Why does the function rewrite other variables?

Tags: c, function, encryption, return, lowercase

I try to write a code in C that takes 26 letters long code from the command-line and that uses the code to encrypt a message.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
        string k = (argv[1]);
    string k_l = make_key(k, 0);    
    string k_u = make_key(k, 1);
}

string make_key(string key, int t)
{
    if (t == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
        {
          key[i] = tolower(key[i]);
        }
    }
    if (t == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
        {
          key[i] = toupper(key[i]);
        }
    }
    return(key);
}
```

When I run the code `string k_l = make_key(k, 0);` it works like I intend it to be and changes all characters to lower case and saves it in k_l. But when I then run `k_u = make_key(k, 1);` the for loop works and changes all characters into upper case. But then it changes not only k_u but also k and k_l.

For example, when I insert "aBc"and run the code I end up with k, k_l and k_u equal to ABC, instead of k_l equal to abc and k = aBc. Can someone tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: What is your `string`? Is it a type alias of `char*`? If the answer is yes, then `k`, `k_l`, `k_u` points the same location. You need to make a copy of `k` and modify the copy.

Comment: There's only one string in this code, and that's `argv[1]`. All the other so-called strings are really just pointers that point to `argv[1]`.

Comment: can you tell me how to solve the problem? Like how can I copy the argv[1] in a variable that is not a pointer?

Comment: `int main(int argc, string argv[])` is invalid C (at least in a hosted implementation). And what is `string`?

Comment: @Amber search `strcpy`, there are tons of examples.

Comment: @KagurazakaKotori maybe `strdup`.

Comment: @kiranBiradar yep, `strdup` is much simpler.

Comment: @KagurazakaKotori thanks that helped a lot, the program runs properly now

Comment: Let me guess, another student destroyed by the horrible CS-50? You ought to clarify if `string` is an evil typedef or the C++ string class.

Comment: Please NEVER EVER `typedef char* string;`.

Comment: @Lundin Since he is using the `string` alias for `argv` it cannot be the C++ `std::string`.

Comment: @kiranBiradar True, but `strdup` is not standard.

Answer (score 3):

Is `string` an alias of `char *`? If it is, I think you can learn something about pointer about C. The first parameter of `make_key`(`key`) pass value by pointer, not by value. This means `k`, `k_l`, `k_u` and `key` point to the same location in memory. So if you modify `key` in `make_key`, you also modify `k`, `k_l` and `k_u`. You can print their addresses like `printf("k: %p, k_l: %p, k_u: %p\n", k, k_l, k_u);` in `main` function. And print `key` in `make_key`. After that, I think you may smell something. Hope this can help you.